# как узнать градус наклона телефона в unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, vector3

Как узнать угол наклона телефона в Unity. Я пытался найти как это сделать на я только нашол как определить угол наклона в Quaternions, а мне нужно в Vector3. Пожалуйста подскажите, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Записываем угол наклона телефона в Quaternion переменную:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gyroscope-attitude.html

```
Quaternion gyroQ = Input.gyro.attitude;
```

Потом переводим наш Quaternion `gyroQ` в углы Эйлера (в Vector3):
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html

```
Vector3 qyroV = gyroQ.eulerAngles;
```

Готово. Вот тебе угол наклона телефона в Vector3 (`qyroV`).

Готовый код:

```
Quaternion gyroQ = Input.gyro.attitude;
Vector3 qyroV = gyroQ.eulerAngles;
```

Покороче:

```
Vector3 qyroV = Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles;
```

Comment: Вообще это легко гуглится... Даже с запросом на русском языке можно найти всю инфу.